# Редирект в .htaccess: написать правильное выражение

Tags: redirect, .htaccess, url

Было:  http://site.ru/komplekty-ukrashenij/yagodnaya-karamel/ 
Стало: http://site.ru/yagodnaya-karamel.html

Или

Было:  http://site.ru/vualetki/v1566/ 
Стало: http://site.ru/v1566.html

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать редирект.
Была бы 1 страница - просто запихнул бы в  Redirect 301, но страниц сотни. Также вопрос индексации, часть старых ссылок проиндексирована с **/** на конце.

По сути, нужно взять значение после последнего `/` в URL и приклеить ему .html.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteRule ^[a-z_\-]*\/([a-z_\-]+)\/? $1.html [R=301, L]
```

Comment: Что то не так. Сервер 500 отдает после этой строки